# Group theoretical characterization of $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q^\star$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$\mathbb Z$ can be characterized in group-theoretic language as the infinite cyclic group. But what kind of a group is $\mathbb Q$ under addition? What about $\mathbb Q^\star$? What kind of subgroup structure do they have, and is there a canonical way to single them out as groups?

Comment: @user18921 That is not correct. For one thing there is torsion.

Comment: @user18921 Yes, by $\mathbb Q^\star$ I mean the multiplicative group of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, I think I get you. $\mathbb{Q}^\star$ is the coproduct of $\aleph_0$ many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ in the category of Abelian groups, not what I said earlier.

Comment: @user18921: This describes $\mathbb{Q}^+$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, true. I really need to revise this stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The additive group $\mathbb Q$ is the minimal non-trivial torsion-free divisible group.

Comment: What does "minimal" mean in this context? Do you mean "initial"?

Comment: No, it is not initial: there are many group homomorphsms from $Q$ to $Q^2$, for example.

Comment: Minimal in the sense that for all non-trivial torsion free divisible groups $G$ there is an injection $Q\to G$.

Comment: But then - a priori - this description doesn't give a unique group? I would therefore say "*a* minimal ...".

Comment: Well, it *is* unique. You just have to prove it —you also have to prove that it is minimal, for that matter! (Torsion free divisible abelian groups are the same thing as $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces)

Comment: One could also describe it as the minimal flat injective abelian group, if on wants to make the statement even more indirect.

Comment: It is not unique in the usual sense of category theory...

Comment: Well, it is not as if that is a sin...  One can well consider ideas and notions that are not those chosen by category theory! Do you agree that all minimal non-zero torsion free abelian groups are isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$? Well, then.

Comment: Of course I agree with that. But uniqueness usually is interepreted in the categorial sense. It is a bit misleading to talk about *the* algebraic closure of a field, for example. However, $\mathbb{Q}$ is also *the* representing object of the forgetful functor from torsion-free divisible abelian groups to sets.

Comment: No, **you** (and others too, of course) interpret the word uniqueness usually in the categorical sense. Most mathematicians I know do not.

Comment: So an algebraic closure of $k$ is unique, for you?

Comment: I am sorry, Martin, but I find a religious approach to the absoluteness of categorical notions irremediably naive and unrepresentative of actual mathematical practice.

Answer (score 3):

There is a presentation $\mathbb{Q} = \langle (x_n)_{n \geq 1} : (n \cdot x_{nk} = x_k)_{n,k \geq 1} \rangle$, where $x_n$ corresponds to $\frac{1}{n}$. This may also be seen as the colimit of the diagram $(\mathbb{N}^+,|) \to \mathsf{Ab}$ which maps each $k \geq 1$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ and a divisibility relation $k|m$ to multiplication by $\frac{m}{k} : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$. Actually, this way arbitrary localizations may be constructed (see for example Eisenbud's book on commutative algebra), and $\mathbb{Q}$ is the localization of the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}$ at $\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$.

The non-trivial subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}$ contain some integer $\neq 0$, which induces an automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}$ so that this integer may be assumed to be $=1$. The classification thus amounts to a classification of the subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. This is well-known, they are of the form $\bigoplus_{p} A_p$, where for each prime $p$ either $A_p$ is either $\langle \frac{1}{p^n} \bmod \mathbb{Z} \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}/p^n$ for some $n$ or $\langle \frac{1}{p^n} \bmod \mathbb{Z} : n \geq 1 \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}/p^\infty$.

As for $\mathbb{Q}^*$, we may use prime factorizations to obtain a direct sum decomposition $\{\pm 1 \} \times \bigoplus_{p} \mathbb{Z}$. I doubt that we can classify the subgroups (without going into set theory ...). At least, we have some canonical subgroups, namely the ones induced by the summands. The subgroups containing $\pm 1$ and $\bigoplus_{p} 2\mathbb{Z}$ correpsond to sub-vector spaces of $\bigoplus_p \mathbb{F}_2$, which are already horrible.

Comment: What does $\bigoplus_p$ mean?

Comment: This is a direct sum indexed by all prime numbers $p$. It abbreviates $\bigoplus\limits_{p \in \mathbb{P}}$.

Comment: Is that isomorphic to the set of all sequences of integers under component-wise addition?

Comment: No, that would be $\prod_p \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Oh, it's [the set of all sequences of almost-all-zero integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum#Direct_sum_of_abelian_groups)?

Answer (score 2):

If you characterize $\mathbb Q$,

you can see that $Aut(\mathbb Q)\cong \mathbb Q^* $ so you can see $\mathbb Q^*$ as a automorphism group of $\mathbb Q$.

And for $\mathbb Q$, there is an easy way by using "Rings";

$\mathbb Q$ is the field of [fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions) of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: But this characterizes $\mathbb Q$ as a field, not as an additive group. Your first comment I wasn't aware of - is it true in general that the multiplicative group of a ring is the automorphism group of its additive group? (That's my quota for saying the word "group" blown for the day...)

Comment: if you know how to constract  field of fraction, you can apply same 
method without mentioning the ring structure but it is a little bit tiring and unnecassary. And It is true for fields, i.e $Aut(F,+)\cong F^*$

Comment: @mesel are you sure it is true that $\mathrm{Aut}(F,+) \cong F^{*}$? I was under the impression that for $F = \mathbb{R}$, it is false that for every $f \in \mathrm{Aut}(F,+),$ there exists $k \in F^*$ such that $f$ is given by $\forall x. f(x)=kx$.

Comment: @user18921: take $f\in Aut(F,+)$ and let $f(1)=k$ then you will see 
that $f(x)=kx$ why ?

Comment: If $f(1) =k,$ we cannot conclude $f(1x) = kx$ because we're not assuming that $f$ preserves products.

Comment: @user18921: start like this, for an pozitive integer $n$, $f(n)=kn$ as $n=1+1+1+...+1$. it must preserve the sum right ?

Comment: $Aut(\mathbb R,+)$ is definitely not $\mathbb R^\times$, for it is not even abelian. To see this, notiec that group homomorphisms $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ are the same thing as $\mathbb Q$-linear maps $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$. More generally, if $F$ is a field, then $Aut(F,+)$ is isomorphic to the group of all $k$-linear automorphisms of th $k$-vector space $F$ with $k\subseteq F$ the «prime field», that is, the intersection of all subfields of $F$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Is it only true for finite fields and $\mathbb Q$ ? I remembered that I saw proof for $\mathbb Q$ and finite fields .

Comment: Well, $\mathbb Q$ is its own prime field, so that is covered by my statement. On the other hand, it is not true for finite fields unless they have a prime number of elements, and that is precisely when they coincide with their prime fields.

Comment: @mesel: The automorphisms you describe combine with the additive group to define $\operatorname{AGL}(1,F)$ which is contained in $\operatorname{A\Gamma L}(1,F)$ (include the Galois group, which are obviously additive automorphisms), which in turn is contained in $\operatorname{AGL}(n,k)$ where $k$ is the prime field of $F$ and $[F:k]=n$ (include the additive automorphisms that are not multiplicative automorphisms).